# Declaring a template member function in a tpp file

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, include, member-functions

I have a class `A` that contains a template member function `AFunc`. To separate definition from declaration, I declare `A` and `AFunc` together in `A.h`. I then define the member function `AFunc` in `A.tpp` and `#include "A.tpp"` at the bottom of the file `A.h`.

To me, this all appears like valid C++. However, the Visual Studio compiler throws the error:

`A.tpp(8,139): error C2244: 'A::AFunc': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration`

The clear solution is to include a declaration for `AFunc` at the top of the `A.tpp` file before `AFunc` is defined. This declaration is in `A.h`, so we want to include `A.h` in `A.tpp` and we want to include `A.tpp` in `A.h`. This inclusion is cyclical.

```
// A.h

class A{
    template <class T>
    void AFunc();
};
#include "A.tpp"
```

```
// A.tpp

template <class T>
void A::AFunc(){
    // definition
}
```

What is the typical solution for dealing with this problem?

Comment: @cigien my bad. A::AFunc is now a template function.

Comment: The file structure is fine. When I put all this code in a single file (which doesn't affect the meaning of the code), I got a similar error message, because I misspelled `AFunc` in the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you giving the compiler the file "A.tpp", or another C++ source file that includes "A.h"? The way you have this structured, I would think the latter would give you the behavior you expect. Apologies, I don't have much VS experience.

Comment: I am compiling using Visual Studio's "Build". I am not sure how to prevent Visual Studio from attempting to compile my TPP files, but I believe you are correct that that is the cause of the error.